# How do I use css3 data-transition?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, css-transitions

css3 seems to have `transition` and `data-transition`.

[I want to use the effects from here](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html), but I'm not quite sure how to get them to work.  I'm coming from css2 and html4 and these things are new to me.  Having read and searched for a few hours already, I'm rather at a loss.

I've tried putting `data-transition: turn;` in my css for an `<a>` element, and I've tried putting it in the html as `<a href='#' data-transition='turn'>link</a>`.

Comment: `transition` is css3 -- `data-transition` is _not_ css3, it is a _jQuery_ feature, not a standard. It is an easy way to attach a transition effect to an element, but you have to include jquery in your page, e.g. the page you linked includes `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>` and several other jquery scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include jQuery and jQuery Mobile in your code to use data-transition,

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js">
```

This example might help you understand how it works since I’m not very familiar with jQuery and jQuery Mobile:
[Here](https://codepen.io/puffierfisher/pen/PoGPdpw) and  [Here](https://www.quanzhanketang.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_transitions.html)

Comment: Ah!  I didn't realize it was a separate jquery package.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `transition` is used inside of CSS

```
.class {
   color: red;
   transition: color 0.25s;
}

/* have the element fade to yellow on hover*/

.class:hover {
   color: yellow;
}
```

`data-transition` is used inside of jQuery frameworks. Try checking out [this page](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html) for info on data-transitions.

Comment: That's actually what I linked to in my question, if you didn't notice...  That's what I'm trying to figure out how to use.  Can you show me how to use that?

Comment: Gotcha, sorry I didn't see the link. I have not used JQuery `data-transition`s before as I've never had a need to do so. My understanding of them is that they are not used much anymore as there isn't much need for them in the modern web. If you want a more in-depth tutorial on how to use them I can recommend this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNPcXOeMRh8